# Why is this not working in Java

Tags: java, consumer

```
import java.util.function.Consumer;

public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Consumer<String> c = (x) --> System.out.println(x.toLowerCase());
        c.accept("Java2s.com");
    }
}
```

with error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: 
>       Unresolved compilation problems: 
>            x cannot be resolved to a variable
>            x cannot be resolved
>       at test.main(test.java:5)

But in all official documents, this is working... Could someone help me?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Eclipse and all to do with just Java and your using Java incorrect syntax. Never try to run uncompilable code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change `-->` to `->` and it should work. It would work only in java8 and later. It's a way to define lambda expression which would consume a string (in your case) and would change the case to lower.

Comment: Thank, but when i changed it, it also mention with the same error and told me i need to change -> to -->